# how to pass props object with "this.$router.push()"

Tags: vue-router

I am using `vue-router 4`.

I passed props object from `this.$router.push()`. But, I got only `[object Object]` as `String` when I printed out.

How Can I do to get the following result as `Object`?

```
{
    roomDimension: {
        width: 15,
        length: 20,
    }
}
```

```
>>> in package.json
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
 "vue-router": "4.0.0-rc.1"
...
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

>>> in router/index.js
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import UploadRoom from "../views/UploadRoom.vue";
import EditRoom from "../views/EditRoom.vue";

const routes = [
...
  {
    path: "/upload-room",
    name: "UploadRoom",
    component: UploadRoom,
  },
  {
    path: "/edit-room",
    name: "EditRoom",
    component: EditRoom,
    props: true,
  },
...
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});
export default router;

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

>>> in UploadRoom.vue
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
this.$router.push({
  name: "EditRoom",
  props: {
    roomData: {
      roomDimension: {
        width: 15,
        length: 20,
      },
    },
  },
});
...
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

>>> in EditRoom.vue
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
import Model from "../components/Model.vue";

export default {
  name: "EditRoom",
  components: {
    Model,
  },
  props: {
    roomData: {
      type: Object, 
      required: true,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // 
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.roomData)
    // got like this >>> [object Object] <<<
  }
};
...
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 1):

Late response, I'm migrating an application from Vue 2 to 3 and I'm having the same problem. I updated to the last version of vue-router and I found the next from the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22):

*If you were relying on passing params that were not defined as part of the path, eg: having a route defined as follows:*

```
{
  path: '/somewhere',
  name: 'somewhere'
}
```

And pushing with an artificial param:

```
router.push({ name: 'somewhere', params: { oops: 'gets removed' } })
```

*This change will break your app. This behavior has worked in some scenarios but has been advised against for years as it's an anti-pattern in routing for many reasons, one of them being reloading the page lose the params. Fortunately, there are multiple alternatives to this anti-pattern:*

- *Putting the data in a store like pinia: this is relevant if the data is used across multiple pages*
- *Move the data to an actual param by defining it on the route's path or pass it as query params: this is relevant if you have small pieces of data that can fit in the URL and should be preserved when reloading the page*
- *Pass the data as state to save it to the History API state*
- *Pass it as a new property to to.meta during navigation guards*

My solution was to put it in the store.

Answer (score 0):

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

> When `props` is set to `true`, the `route.params` will be set as the component props.

You have to put `props: true`. Without it, your data will be delivered in `$route.params.roomData`. Not in props.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

>>> You have to put props = true. Without it, your data will be delivered in $route.params.roomData. Not in props. <<<

I already set `props:true` in `router/index.js`. It doesn't work for me.